# How do epochs effect deep learning models?

Tags: r, machine-learning, deep-learning, h2o

I built a simple deep learning regression model with `h2o` (below). The model predicts sepal length in the R iris dataset. I notice that as I increase the epochs, the model accuracy (r^2) increases (Figure 1).

By increasing the number of epochs, am I overfitting the model in a detrimental way or am I increasing the model accuracy in a beneficial way?

```
library(datasets)
library(h2o)

df <- iris

df.hex <- as.h2o(df)

model <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 2:5, y = 1, df.hex,
                          hidden = c(200, 200, 200, 200, 200),
                          epochs = 5,
                          variable_importances=T)

perf_dl <- h2o.performance(model)
rsq_dl <- h2o.r2(perf_dl)
```

---

---

**Figure 1**

[image]

```
# Note this code plots the data from the deep learning runs in the previous code
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(epochs = c(5, 10, 100, 300, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000), rsq = c(0.77, 0.70, 0.57, 0.75, 0.87, 0.92, 0.97, 0.96, 0.98))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(epochs, rsq))
p + geom_point(aes(size = 7)) + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), size = 1)
```

Comment: This is such a small toy dataset, you can't really judge how deep learning performs by running experiments on it.  You have 5 hidden layers, and each one has more neurons than the dataset has rows.  It's not a good use case.

Answer (score 4):

The typical image which is usually shown in this situation is

[image]

Please note that the sweet spot (50 epochs, in the image) depends on the network, the problem and the data. Determining when to stop is an unsolved problem, but early stopping is a popular choice.

Source: My still unpublished, but finished masters thesis. It is not public right now due to bureaucratic reasons of my university.

Comment: Interestingly, I do not notice error increase with an increase in epochs.

Comment: @Borealis This is not necessarily the case. But usually.

Answer (score 1):

Gradient Descent is an optimization procedure which updates the weights in the neural network in an iterative fashion. If we train the network for a few epochs, it leads to underfitting of the data. This means the neural network cannot capture the underlying trend of the data.
Now, as we increase the number of epochs, it will reach an optimal situation where we will get maximum accuracy on the training set. Beyond this stage, if we keep increasing the number of epochs, it will lead to overfitting of the data. That is the accuracy in the training set increases whereas that of validation set decreases. This means the network does not reflect the reality of the data because it captures the noise in the data as well.

So the answer is we cannot say beforehand the number of epochs to train the neural network so that it performs the best. It is a hypermeter that needs to be tuned. We can only use some heuristics and fix some number of epochs to train the neural network while monitoring the accuracy on training and validation sets.

So in the conclusion, the number of epochs for training the neural network varies from one problem to another because it is highly related to the dataset and the complexity of the network which you are using. It is one of the hyperparameters that needs to be tuned during the training of the neural network.